# Algorithms: Find the best table to play (standing gambler problem)

Tags: algorithms

***Preface***

This is not code golf. I'm looking at an interesting problem and hoping to solicit comments and suggestions from my peers. This question is not about [card counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_counting) (exclusively), rather, it is about determining the best table to engage based on observation. Assume if you will some kind of brain implant that makes worst case time / space complexity (on any given architecture) portable to the human mind. Yes, this is quite subjective. Assume a [French deck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_card#French) without the use of wild cards.

***Background***

I recently visited a casino and saw more bystanders than players per table, and wondered what selection process turned bystanders into betting players, given that most bystanders had funds to play (chips in hand).

***Scenario***

You enter a casino. You see n tables playing a variant of [Blackjack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackjack), with y of them playing [Pontoon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontoon_%28game%29). Each table plays with an indeterminate amount of card decks, in an effort to obfuscate the [house advantage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casino_game#House_advantage).

Each table has a varying minimum bet. You have Z currency on your person. You want to find the table where:

- The least amount of card decks are in use
- The minimum bet is higher than a table using more decks, but you want to maximize the amount of games you can play with Z.
- Net losses, per player are lowest (I realize that this is, in most answers, considered to be  incidental noise, but it could illustrate a broken shuffler)

***Problem***

You can magically observe every table. You have X rounds to sample, in order to base your decision. For this purpose, every player takes no more than 30 seconds to play.

What algorithm(s) would you use to solve this problem, and what is their worst case complexity? Do you:

- Play Pontoon or Blackjack ?
- What table do you select ?
- How many rounds do you need to observe (what is the value of X), given that the casino can use no more than 8 decks of cards for either game? Each table has between 2 and 6 players.
- How long did you stand around while finding a table?

I'm calling this the "**standing gambler problem**" for lack of a better term. Please feel free to refine it.

***Additional***

Where would this be useful if not in a casino?

***Final***

I'm not looking for a magic gambling bullet. I just noticed a problem which became a bone that my brain simply won't stop chewing. I'm especially interested in applications way beyond visiting a casino.

Comment: Interesting quesiton.  I'm not sure this is the right site for this.  I don't know why or where it would fit better, it just doesn't feel right here.  Perhaps I'm wrong...

Comment: @Walter - I wasn't sure either. There are sites dedicated to various games, but it isn't likely that the users of those sites understand complexity, or even what an algorithm is. It's too 'meta' for SO, I'm wondering if it can find a home here.

Comment: I don't know it kinda sounds like a Poisson process. Maybe the people at math.stackexchange.com might know.

Comment: @Conrad, perhaps. However, I suspect someone here might have some ideas, which ended my debate on asking the question in the first place :)

Comment: Your criteria are not even correct. At blackjack you do not care about historical net losses at a table, you just care what the relative percentage of face cards is that you have seen. Knowing the size of the deck also isn't very important because your count is just a running figure; everytime you see a face card you subtract a point, every low card you add a point, start playing when count is 10+ and bet big when it is 15+ is the basics of a typical blackjack system.

Comment: @Jeremy, I noted that (historical losses being likely insignificant). I think that the problem is well defined, you are free to edit it. The casino preface was simply the easiest way to articulate the problem.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not even see a problem statement. I can only assume that the problem is to maximize winnings, then the questions you ask are not important to the algorithm. I don't care how many rounds I observe, I just observe until I have an edge against the house and then I push that edge. If I can always wait until I have an edge and always switch tables to the table with the best edge then the algorithm is very simple.

Comment: @Jeremy, I am asking _when_ to sit at a table and _which one_ to select. Not how to win. The game begins once seated. Should I edit my question for additional clarity?

Comment: @Jeremy the running count as a percentage of remaining cards is pertinent IF you begin watching at the beginning of the shoe.  A count of 10 or 15 in favor of the player is more favorable at the end of the shoe than the beginning.  Oversimplified example: only 10 cards remain in the shoe and we are at an incredibly large count in our favor.  All remaining cards are good for us.  7 deck shoe maximum positive count of X.  Current positive Y. one deck max + Z. Current positive A. if Y/X > A/Z is it better to play on the 7 deck table?  i leave the percentage exercise to you.

Comment: @aking1012 Agreed, the depth into total shoe size along with the betting spread would all go into determining the expected value of the count at a particular table. But this is just a formula, it isn't an algorithm. I still don't see where the OP is going. What you and I are describing is how you would make these decisions given you are looking for an outcome of getting paid. There is no algorithm, only a math problem.

Comment: He probably just meant math problem/loop implementation.

Comment: It looks to me like - i want to make a blackjack/poker bot and don't know how....plz splain the math.

Comment: @aking1012 - That is decidedly _not_ the case. It's a problem that I encountered, I've been chewing on it and I thought other people might enjoy chewing on it too. Keep in mind, all I'm trying to determine is "what table to play" :)

Comment: @Tim Post, the answer is (if you want to keep your money), none of them.

Comment: This is a fun problem, but I cannot think of any real world applications.

Comment: Because this isn't written in math speak, I take it you aren't a stats major, but probably a programmer. I would recommend doing this as a simulation.  Once you get some mildly realistic random number generators with appropriate distributions, it can be fairly easy to write a simulation model that matches your mental model of the world.  By rerunning the model over and over and collecting the results, you can learn about the characteristics of the model without necesarily needing to do the much harder math involved in proving a strategy is better than another.

Answer (score 1):

If I can concurrently examine all tables even while playing then:
Given that all games progress at the same speed for simplicity...(i could adjust for this)

```
while(not satisfied with winnings)
 keepcurrenttable == 1 || Wait for positive count threshold on any one table  
  if Z/(min bet)>%chance of win*payout  
    next  
  else  
    Play hand according to standard counting rules.  
  endif
if (%chance of win on another table*payout on another table > same for current) && Z/(min bet)>%chance of win*payout
  change tables  
 elseif currenttable %chance of win*payout >
  keepcurrenttable=1
 else
  keepcurrenttable=0
 endif
next
```

still some bugs in there and doesn't account for EVERYTHING, but you get where I'm going

there's a lot more to %chance of win

number of players should be minimally pertinent(more players == faster burning through decks)

does less players mean I can play more hands concurrently?(that would require heavier weight on player count)

additionally, count threshold could be defined with a risk appetite meter.